# What wavelengths of light do occur in reverse Cherenkov radiations?

Tags: wavelength, cherenkov-radiation

[Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation) works much like a sonic boom, where a particle faster than light in that medium produces shorter wavelengths of light when passing through it (blue). According to the same article, there is also an effect called [reverse Cherenkov radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation#Reverse_Cherenkov_effect), where instead of emitting "in front" or in the direction of the particle, it emits backwards.

Now, I'm not entirely sure if I understood the science behind it correctly, as it stands now I understand it as a sort of blueshift phenomenon, where the moving particle "compresses" the wavelength of the light moving before it. If that's the case, reverse Cherenkov radiation should have a longer wavelength, and I simply want to know if I got it wrong, and if so, which wavelength can be observed in the other.